# i’m in possession of something stolen from a big company and can’t return it

Tags: sharia, sadaqah, theft

i have become more religious and aware of my duties and the rights of others under islam, and i would like to right the wrongs for proper repentance.

i have products from large companies that are not rightfully mine that i cannot return; worn, used, dated, and so on. it’s not possible for me replace the items since they no longer exist and i cannot replace the value of the items by purchasing something equivalent in value to return. it is also not possible for me to pay them back anonymously although i am still trying. one establishment is trying to see if i can possibly pay a charity on their behalf for the value of the item

i believe the last option for product i cannot return is to simply pay the value of the item as charity. but if i do pay the value as charity (1) what should i do with the item that is not rightfully mine?

(2) what if the company forgives me for what i have done, what do i do with the items then?

Comment: From your text, you did not steal some SpaceX spaceship from Elon Musk and set off to Mars, but rather stole some minor items from a *big* company that might not even be aware of the individual thefts. Depending on the value of the items, it will bring more costs to the company to reclaim the value. Waiting for some answer based on Islam.